# D3 Canvas Network does not appear unless it is manually refreshed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am adding a few nodes to the canvas manually and then few links. I am expecting the network to appear immediately but it doesn't. after hours of investigation, I found that when the nodes are just added, adding the links picks the `x`,`y` attributes of nodes as `Nan` and make the nodes disappear.

So I added a `refresh` button so that I can manually refresh the network later once the nodes are settled.

Is there a better way to solve this problem? I have hundreds of nodes being sent over real-time so initially, I won't have anything and later an external service will call the `addNodeCanvas` & `addLinkCanvas`.

On running the following code, nothing will appear initially, after a few seconds pressing the `refresh` button will show the network.

---

**EDIT**

As per Shashank's answer below, I have got rid of `onload` functionality.

Please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa1024/s69a5b2r/2/), got rid of `onload`; I am calling the refresh method just after linking the nodes but nothing shows up unless the nodes settle down.

Please compare this with this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa1024/mojxhbye/1/), I got rid of all the links, now the nodes appear instantaneously.

**I found that when the nodes are just added, adding the links picks the `x`,`y` attributes of nodes as `Nan` and make the nodes disappear.**

---

Original Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="connect1();">
  <canvas width="300" height="100"></canvas>
  <button id="ref" onclick="refresh()">refresh </button>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      width = canvas.width,
      height = canvas.height;

    var links = [],
      nodes = [];
    var graph = {
        nodes,
        links
      },
      wsConn;
    refresh();

    function connect1() {
      addNodeCanvas("A");
      addNodeCanvas("B");
      addNodeCanvas("C");
      addNodeCanvas("D");
      addNodeCanvas("E");
      addLinkCanvas("A", "B");
      addLinkCanvas("A", "C");
      addLinkCanvas("D", "C");
      addLinkCanvas("E", "D");
      addLinkCanvas("E", "B");
    }

    function addNodeCanvas(nodeName, g) {
      var node = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        id: nodeName,
        grp: g
      };
      var n = nodes.push(node);
      //console.log(node);
      refresh();
    }
    
    function addLinkCanvas(idSrc, idTarget) {
      if (idSrc != idTarget) {
        var s = {},
          t = {};
        nodes.forEach(function(curNode) {
          if (typeof curNode.id != "undefined") {
            if (curNode.id == idSrc) {
              s = curNode;
            }
            if (curNode.id == idTarget) {
              t = curNode;
            }
          }
        });
        //console.log( { s,t});
        links.push({
          source: s,
          target: t
        });
      };
    }

    function refresh() {
      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
          return d.id;
        }))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

      simulation
        .nodes(nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked)
        .force("link")
        .links(links);
      d3.select(canvas)
        .call(d3.drag()
          .container(canvas)
          .subject(dragsubject)
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

      function ticked() {
        var margin = 20;
        nodes.forEach(function(d) {
          d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
          d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
        });

        function dblclick() {
          nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            d.fx = d.fy = null;
          })
        };
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        context.beginPath();
        links.forEach(drawLink);
        context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
        context.stroke();
        context.beginPath();
        nodes.forEach(drawNode);
      }

      function dragsubject() {
        return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
      }
      var clickDate = new Date();
      var difference_ms;

      function dragstarted() {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.subject.x));
        d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.subject.y));
      }

      function dragged() {
        d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.x));
        d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.y));
      }


      function dragended() {}

      function drawLink(d) {
        context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
        context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
      }

      var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20),
        labelColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']);

      function drawNode(d) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(d.x + 10, d.y);
        context.arc(d.x, d.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
        context.stroke();
        context.fillStyle = nodeColors(d.grp);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        context.beginPath();
        context.font = (d.labelSize ? d.labelSize : 10) + 'px Arial';
        context.fillStyle = labelColors(d.grp);
        context.fillText(d.id ? d.id : d.grp, d.x, d.y);
        context.closePath();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `nodes` and the `links` haven't been added to the respective arrays when you call the `refresh()` method.

Here's the explanation to when the `onload` function gets called (mentioned in the [MSDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

So by the time refresh is called after setting all the variables (in the `<script>` tag, the `connect1` hasn't been called yet which means there are no nodes and no links and hence no graph. But when you click the the refresh button, the `connect1` has already been executed and the nodes, links have been added which leads to drawing the graph.

Amongst many solutions to this, here's one approach: (calling `refresh` in the `connect1` function)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="connect1();">
    <canvas width="300" height="100"></canvas>
    <!--button id="ref" onclick="refresh()">refresh </button-->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      width = canvas.width,
      height = canvas.height;
    var links =[] , nodes = [] ;

    var graph={nodes,links}, wsConn;    

function connect1(){

    addNodeCanvas("A");
    addNodeCanvas("B");
    addNodeCanvas("C");
    addNodeCanvas("D");
    addNodeCanvas("E");
    addLinkCanvas("A","B");
    addLinkCanvas("A","C");
    addLinkCanvas("D","C");
    addLinkCanvas("E","D");
    addLinkCanvas("E","B");
    
    refresh();
}



function addNodeCanvas(nodeName,g) {
  var node = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    id: nodeName,
    grp:g
  };
  var n = nodes.push(node);
}


function addLinkCanvas(idSrc, idTarget) {

    if (idSrc != idTarget) {
    var s = {},
      t = {};
    nodes.forEach(function(curNode) {
      if (typeof curNode.id != "undefined") {
        if (curNode.id == idSrc) {
          s = curNode;
        }
        if (curNode.id == idTarget) {
          t = curNode;
        }
      }
    });

    links.push({
      source: s,
      target: t
    });
  };

}




    function refresh() {

            var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { 
                return d.id; 
            }))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

        simulation
            .nodes(nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked)
            .force("link")
            .links(links);
        d3.select(canvas)
            .call(d3.drag()
                .container(canvas)
                .subject(dragsubject)
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));


        function ticked() {
            var margin = 20;
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
                d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
            });

            function dblclick() {
                nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.fx = d.fy = null;
                })
            };
            context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            context.beginPath();
            links.forEach(drawLink);
            context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            nodes.forEach(drawNode);

        }

        function dragsubject() {
            return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
        }
        var clickDate = new Date();
        var difference_ms;

        function dragstarted() {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.subject.x));
            d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.subject.y));
        }

        function dragged() {
            d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.x));
            d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.y));
        }


        function dragended() {
           
        }


        function drawLink(d) {
            context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
            context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
        }

        var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20),
            labelColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']);

        function drawNode(d) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(d.x + 10, d.y);
            context.arc(d.x, d.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle = nodeColors(d.grp);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
            context.beginPath();
            context.font = (d.labelSize ? d.labelSize : 10) + 'px Arial';
            context.fillStyle = labelColors(d.grp);
            context.fillText(d.id ? d.id : d.grp, d.x, d.y);
            context.closePath();
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT: Call refresh after every node/link addition:**

This [bl.ocks snippet](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) helped in knowing what has to be done to add a dynamic force layout which clearly indicates that the setup has to be done just once but the nodes/links attachment to the simulation can be done any number of times. Also, I'm using `.restart()` that:

> Restarts the simulation’s internal timer and returns the simulation. In conjunction with simulation.alphaTarget or simulation.alpha, this method can be used to “reheat” the simulation during interaction, such as when dragging a node, or to resume the simulation after temporarily pausing it with simulation.stop.

Here's the doc link: [d3 simulation restart](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_restart)

The example I refer to is a SVG one but the logic is pretty much the same for a canvas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body >
    <canvas width="900" height="600"></canvas>
    <button id="ref" onclick="refresh()">refresh </button>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script>

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        width = canvas.width,
        height = canvas.height;

    var links =[] , nodes = [] ;
    var graph={nodes,links}, wsConn;
    
    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { 
        return d.id; 
      }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
    refresh();

    connect1();

function connect1(){

    addNodeCanvas("A");
    addNodeCanvas("B");
    addNodeCanvas("C");
    addNodeCanvas("D");
    addNodeCanvas("E");
    addLinkCanvas("A", "B");
    addLinkCanvas("A", "C");
    addLinkCanvas("D", "C");
    addLinkCanvas("E", "D");
    addLinkCanvas("E", "B");
    refresh();
}



function addNodeCanvas(nodeName,g) {
  var node = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    id: nodeName,
    grp:g
  };
  var n = nodes.push(node);
  //console.log(node);
  refresh();
}


function addLinkCanvas(idSrc, idTarget) {

    if (idSrc != idTarget) {
    var s = {},
      t = {};
    nodes.forEach(function(curNode) {
      if (typeof curNode.id != "undefined") {
        if (curNode.id == idSrc) {
          s = curNode;
        }
        if (curNode.id == idTarget) {
          t = curNode;
        }
      }
    });

//console.log( { s,t});
    links.push({
      source: s,
      target: t
    });
  };
 refresh();
}




    function refresh() {

        simulation
            .nodes(nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked);
            
        simulation
            .force("link")
            .links(links);
            
    simulation.alpha(1).restart();            
        d3.select(canvas)
            .call(d3.drag()
                .container(canvas)
                .subject(dragsubject)
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));


        function ticked() {
            var margin = 20;
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
                d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
            });

            function dblclick() {
                nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.fx = d.fy = null;
                })
            };
            context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            context.beginPath();
            links.forEach(drawLink);
            context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            nodes.forEach(drawNode);

        }

        function dragsubject() {
            return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
        }
        var clickDate = new Date();
        var difference_ms;

        function dragstarted() {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.subject.x));
            d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.subject.y));
        }

        function dragged() {
            d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.x));
            d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.y));
        }


        function dragended() {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);

            // Time between 2 ends of drag:
            difference_ms = (new Date()).getTime() - clickDate.getTime();
            clickDate = new Date();
            // if the time between these 2 ends of drag is short enough, then
            // it's considered a double click:
            if (difference_ms < 200) {
                // And we can release the node:
                simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
                d3.event.subject.fx = null;
                d3.event.subject.fy = null;
            }
        }


        function drawLink(d) {
            context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
            context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
        }

        var nodeColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20),
            labelColors = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']);

        function drawNode(d) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(d.x + 10, d.y);
            context.arc(d.x, d.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle = nodeColors(d.grp);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
            context.beginPath();
            context.font = (d.labelSize ? d.labelSize : 10) + 'px Arial';
            context.fillStyle = labelColors(d.grp);
            context.fillText(d.id ? d.id : d.grp, d.x, d.y);
            context.closePath();
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/my3cnwg9/1/). Hope this helps.

Comment: please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa1024/s69a5b2r/2/) , got rid of onload ; i am calling the refresh method just after linking the nodes but nothing shows up unless the nodes settle down. please compare this with this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa1024/mojxhbye/1/), I got rid of all the links, now the nodes appear instantaneously

Comment: I got a question for you: why are you calling `refresh` after every node addition or link addition? Could you please try getting rid of all the `refresh` calls except the one in `connect1` i.e. after linking the nodes? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLnd58xo/)

Comment: I have hundreds of nodes being sent over real-time so initially, I won't have anything and later an external service will call the addNodeCanvas & addLinkCanvas via websocket, this is why i want to call refresh whenever a node or link is added. these jsfiddles are just simulating the problem i am seeing with 100 of nodes and links.

Comment: Okay. Gotcha. Let me dig deep and get back to you then.

Comment: @nyi Please check the edits and let me know if that works out. Apologies for the first case, my bad, as I've never used this d3 simulation. Had to go through the docs and examples.

Comment: It's looking great @Shashank, I have spent hours to solve this problem, you made my day. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)